# I can't read the value of text input in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My problem is when I want to display the value given by the user in the **Text input** text field.

When I want to get the text value from the input I get an empty value and I cannot display anything in the label field .

Here is my code :

- The **kv** file :

  - ```
    MainGridLayout:

    <MainGridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: my_text_input
            text: root.text_input_1
            hint_text :'Operations'
            multiline:False
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            font_size: '30dp'
        Label:
            text: root.Display_text
            font_size: '45dp'
    StackLayout:
        Button:
            text:"+"
            spacing: .2, .2
            size: 85, 85
            size_hint: None, None
            on_press: root.on_button_plus()
    ```
- The **py** file :

  - ```py
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


    # different layouts:

    class MainGridLayout(GridLayout):

         text_input_1 = StringProperty()
         Display_text = StringProperty()

         def on_button_plus(self):
             print(f'{self.text_input_1}')


         # run application:

         class CalculatorApp(App):
             pass

         CalculatorApp().run()
    ```

Comment: Please reformat your code with correct indentations. Also avoid bullets as they are used for different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the variables `text_input_1` and `Display_text`. To display the text from the `my_text_input` on the label you can add `text: my_text_input.text` instead of `text: root.Display_text`. Now, when the text of `my_text_input` changes, the label's text will change automatically and you don't need any functions. In `on_button_plus()` method you can do the same and print `my_text_input`'s text using its `text` property (from all `MainGridLayout`'s `ids` you take only `my_text_input` and print its text). The line `text: root.text_input_1` unnecessary, too.

Here is my editted version of your code:

The **.py** file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MainGridLayout(GridLayout):

    def on_button_plus(self):
        print(f'{self.ids.my_text_input.text}')


class CalculatorApp(App):
    pass


CalculatorApp().run()
```

The **.kv** file

```
MainGridLayout:

<MainGridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: my_text_input
            hint_text :'Operations'
            multiline:False
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            font_size: '30dp'
        Label:
            text: my_text_input.text  # change the text automatically
            font_size: '45dp'
    StackLayout:
        Button:
            text:"+"
            spacing: .2, .2
            size: 85, 85
            size_hint: None, None
            on_press: root.on_button_plus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function in **MainGridLayout**, `on_new_text`, that takes as a parameter a TextInput and updates `text_input_1` with its value.

In the kv file I have set the `on_text` property of the TextInput to the `on_new_text` function and gave the TextInput as a parameter. Every time you modify the text input, the `on_new_text` function will be called, modifying the `text_input_1` property.

You can find more properties like `on_text` in the kivy documentation.

The **kv** file:

```
MainGridLayout:

<MainGridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: my_text_input
            hint_text :'Operations'
            multiline:False
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            font_size: '30dp'
            on_text: root.on_new_text(self)
        Label:
            text: root.Display_text
            font_size: '45dp'
    StackLayout:
        Button:
            text:"+"
            spacing: .2, .2
            size: 85, 85
            size_hint: None, None
            on_press: root.on_button_plus()
```

The **py** file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


# different layouts:


class MainGridLayout(GridLayout):

    text_input_1 = StringProperty()
    Display_text = StringProperty()

    def on_new_text(self, text_input):
        self.text_input_1 = text_input.text

    def on_button_plus(self):
        print(f'{self.text_input_1}')


class CalculatorApp(App):
    pass


CalculatorApp().run()
```